# Rendering Current Page With PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs, mern

I am building an analytics dashboard using the MERN stack (Express, Node) are the Important things to highlight.

As part of a dash view, I was trying to find if it's possible to trigger a PhantomJS call to create a pdf report using a button on the page itself.

Given you need to be logged in to see your own analytics, I can not just run phantom from the command line and pass it in the URL of one of the dashboard pages since it requires a login and queries to be made.

Is it possible to do this with phantomJS?

Comment: Would be great if you could describe a bit more about - what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is there any error? What is not understandable? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question.

Example:

[main.js]

```
  const dashboardToPdfCtrl = require("./controllers/phantom/pdf");  
  router.route("/api/dashboard/phantom").post(dashboardToPdfCtrl.createPdf);   
  router.route("/api/dashboard/phantom/html")
     .post(dashboardToPdfCtrl.createDashboard);
```

When the user clicks on the "button" you can validate the USER according to the architecture of your application.

[pdf.js]

```
 exports.createPdf= async (req, res) => {
            if (!req.user || !req.user.sub) {
        return res
          .status(401)
          .send({ message: 'No authorization token was found' });
      }
          const instance = await phantom.create();
          const page = await instance.createPage();

         const settings = {
            operation: "POST",
            encoding: "utf8",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
              user: req.body.userId,
              anyDataYouNeedToRender: req.body.anyDataYouNeedToRender
            })
          };
    //POST request to /api/dashboard/phantom/html
            await page.open(
            `${process.env.HOST}:${
              process.env.PORT
            }/api/dashboard/phantom/html`,
            settings
          );
    //Save the content of /public/dashboard/dashboard.html with received data to pdf
          const pageSaved = await page.render(
            path.resolve(`./public/dashboard/file.pdf`)
          );

          if (pageSaved) await instance.exit();
        }

        exports.createDashboard = (req, res) => {
          res.render(
            path.resolve("./public/dashboard/dashboard.html"),
            { user: req.body.user,
              anyDataYouNeedToRender: req.body:anyDataYouNeedToRender
            }
          );
        };
```

Is that what you were looking for? I want to help you, feel free to ask detalization.

P.S. As friends told before in comments, it will be great if you give us more information to understend you goal.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for thank you! i was not sure if it was possible to authenticate with a headless browser.

Comment: @justwhaatiam I am happy to help!